# Displaying non-roman characters in a string

Tags: iphone, fonts, nsstring, utf8-decode

In my app I receive from a remote host a string that is like this:
 "01 - \U00ab\U00d3\U00ba\U00d2\U00c2\U00b4\U00d5\U00b7\U00d5\U00e8\U00a4\U00d2\U00b9\U00b7\U00cd\U00a7 - \U00c8\U00d4\U00c3\U00d4\U00be\U00c3 \U00cd\U00d3\U00e4"

I know that this is a string in Thai language.  When I display it using UILabel of NSLog, it shows up as:

01 - «ÓºÒÂ´Õ·Õè¤Ò¹·Í§ - ÈÔÃÔ¾Ã ÍÓä

Is there a way to make the string show up correctly using Thai font?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you convert this string as an NSString?

Comment: I just do:
NSString *str = receivedString;

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using something like

```
+ (id)stringWithCString:(const char *)cString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
```

if you know what the specific encoding is and it is not UTF8, or

```
+ (id)stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)bytes
```

if that's what it is. Then the string should display. I expect the remote host says something about the encoding of the string in the response?

Comment: I have tried the following, but it still shows the strange-looking string that I have shown in my question above:
`code`

                const char *cstr = [receivedString UTF8String];
         myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstr];